# How to work with specific positions of string in Java?

Tags: java, string, position, substring

I need to remove some chars at specific positions of a string in Java.

Is there something equivalent to `std::string.erase()` from C++ in Java? If not, could someone show me a quick example of how to loop on each character of a string so I can count them and get the position of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to change the `String` object itself since `Strings` are immutable in Java, however, you could generate a new `String` object based on removing chars from the old `String`.

Alternatively, if you work with something like `StringBuilder` / `StringBuffer` that becomes possible as these classes provide [a `delete(start,end)` function](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete%28int,%20int%29)

Oh and since you asked about manipulating characters in a `String`, there is the `length()` method which gives you the length of the `String` and also the [`charAt(position)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

Answer (score 2):

try here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 2):

Since `String` itself is immutable, there's no trivial way to do that.

You could use [`substring`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to construct the new `String`: `orig.substring(0, index1) + orig.substring(index2)`.

However, if you do repeated string manipulation, then [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) might be better, both for performance *and* usability reasons:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(orig);
b.replace(index1, index2, "");
```

`StringBuilder` is pretty much the mutable equivalent to a `String`. Earlier versions used `StringBuffer`, which has the exact same methods but is synchronized, which is not usually needed.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

There are lots of good methods that will get you the index of characters (`indexOf`) and substrings (`substring`)

After looking at the documentation for erase in c++, it seems like you can use 2 calls to `substring` to mimic that behavior. You might want to create a `StringUtils` class and implement your own erase based on the desired API.  Note that Strings in java are immutable so you can't exactly duplicate that behaviour -- every operation on a string that changes the string returns a new string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial of string manipulation in Java:  [String Manipulation](http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutor7.htm)

You can also look at this one:  [Java - String Class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The counting of the characters can be achieved using the `toCharArray()` method (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

For more advanced String manipulation (erase etc..) you should youse a StringBuilder/StringBuffer (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#deleteCharAt(int))